# Enquiries on AltBeacon Specifications

Tags: altbeacon

Hi everyone/developers,

I have a project on using Android smartphones as a Beacon and I am using AltBeacon for its Open and Interoperable Proximity Beacon Specification. Furthermore, I have already understood some of its specification such as the UUID, Major, Minor. As of now, I am in the testing stages.

I have attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5K3a.png) and based on the BeaconScope app, could someone explain to me what is:

1. data1
2. power in dBm (Higher, the Better???, or vice versa)
3. rssi
4. detection rate
5. stabilized/stabilised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two fields are part of the AltBeacon packet:

- data1: a one byte field that can be used to communicate any value the beacon hardware manufacturer desires.  Hardware battery beacons often put the battery level in this field, with 255 meaning a full battery and 0 meaning an empty battery.
- power: Assuming the beacon is properly calibrated, this value indicates the average RSSI the user should see when the beacon is 1 meter away.  This is used for distance estimates.

The third field, RSSI, comes from the operating system and tells you the signal level of the beacon packet.  -59 dBm is a typical signal at 1m, with more negative values indicating a weaker signal (often further away) and less negative value indicating a stronger signal (often closer)

The last two fields are quality analysis measurements made by the BeaconScope app based on how it is receiving the beacon:

- detection rate:  This is the number of packets per second (pps) seen on average since the beacon was most recently detected.  At short distances, this is typically slightly lower than the actual transmission rate of the beacon since not all packets get receivied.
- stabilized: (North American spelling) is true if the averaging interval for RSSI measurements (20 seconds) has been reached.  Until it is stabilized, the running average RSSI field will have a larger fluctuation.

I'm the author of the app, and one of the original authors of the AltBeacon spec.